# Addition of values from two files using Scanner isn't working

Tags: java, arrays, file, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I have a two data files, `Text1_txt` and `Text2_txt`. The structure and data within these files are as follows.

Text_1.txt:

```
86.0    1.2356    -0.6325

25.0    1.0512  0.97852

30.0    2.6581  2.25147

18.0    -0.2358 1.5689

90.0    3.5687  -0.8974

88.0    1.9852  -0.1478

70.0    2.0789  -1.2564

87.0    9.2547  1.1120

55.0    -4.1254 1.3611
```

The left hand side column is an important column in this data file. Let's say this is an ID number. In my program I create a search based on this column.

Now the data of the 2nd file, Text_2.txt:

```
3.57323240   -3.33283870     2.34080000 

3.57322470   -3.33283680     2.34070000 

3.57323800   -3.33286720     2.34080000 

3.57324670   -3.33288070     2.34080000 

3.57323740   -3.33292520     2.34100000 

3.57322660   -3.33292540     2.34110000 

3.57318870   -3.33289200     2.34110000 

3.57319510   -3.33287860     2.34110000 

3.57327090   -3.33284380     2.34070000
```

The main similarity between these two files is that they have same number of Columns and Rows. My program is to add the values of these two file. The addition depends upon the key attribute ID. I have an array in my program containing ID values. I compare these array values with the values in `Text_1`. If the value of the ID column is the same as the ID value in the array, I then add up this row with corresponding row of `Text_2` file. That means the 4th row of `Text_1.txt` is add with 4th Row of Text_2.txt. This should happen in the code below. But this code adds the value of the 1st row of `Text_2.txt` with all the Rows of `Text1_txt`, but this is not what I want.

```
import Jama.Matrix;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class T5 {
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
    double arr[]= new double[]{86.0,12.0,55.0,90.0,77.0,22.0,25.0,33.0,45.0,20.0,23.0};// The array with which the value of file Text_1 compare
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    Scanner x= new Scanner(new File("D:\\Text_1.txt"));
    Scanner y=new Scanner(new File("D:\\Text_2.txt"));
    while(y.hasNext()) {
        double x1=y.nextDouble();
        double y1=y.nextDouble();
        double z1=y.nextDouble();
        Matrix ini_x=new Matrix(new double[][]{{x1},{y1},{z1}});
        while (x.hasNext()) {
            double d = x.nextDouble();
            double e = x.nextDouble();
            double f = x.nextDouble();
            double index = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, d);
            if (index >= 0 && index <= arr.length) {
               System.out.println("Element within the array" + d);//output those number which are both in array and file
                Matrix A = new Matrix(new double[][]{{d}, {e}, {f}});
                ini_x.print(9,6);
                Matrix c=ini_x.plus(A);// Matrix addition (add the first row of Text_2.txt with all the four rows which found using binarySearch.
                c.print(9,6);
            }

        }
    }

}
}
```

Any suggestion about this matter is welcome.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How many rows are there in a file? You are making things very complicated for yourself by having one loop within the other. If the files are not to large I would read them first (one by one) into memory and then starting to look for rows to add.

Comment: "4th row of Text_1.txt is add with 4th Row of Text_2.txt", 4th row of Text_1.txt is "18.0    -0.2358 1.5689"? and 4th Row of Text_2.txt is "3.57324670   -3.33288070     2.34080000"?  assume i understand correctly, but 18.0 is not in your defined array..i'm confused..TAT

Comment: @qfrank This is just an example. Actually 1st row of text_1.txt add with 1st row of text_2.txt.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson This two are really a big data file of 88000 rows. I just write down some portion of this huge file.

Comment: Well for one thing you shouldn't have one loop inside the other, since both files contains same number of rows then read them in parallell. Read line `n` from file 1, read line `n` from file 2, search `arr` for id and add if found, next `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this is what u want...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double arr[] = new double[]{
            86.0,
            12.0,
            55.0,
            90.0,
            77.0,
            22.0,
            25.0,
            33.0,
            45.0,
            20.0,
            23.0
    };// The array with which the value of file Text_1 compare
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    Scanner t1 = new Scanner(TestJama.class.getResourceAsStream("/Text_1.txt"));
    Scanner t2 = new Scanner(TestJama.class.getResourceAsStream("/Text_2.txt"));
    while (t1.hasNext())
    {
        double t1_id    = t1.nextDouble();
        double t1_col2    = t1.nextDouble();
        double t1_col3    = t1.nextDouble();
        Matrix t1_matrix = new Matrix(new double[][]{
                {t1_id},
                {t1_col2},
                {t1_col3}
        });

        //read the same row from Text_2.txt
        double t2_col1 = t2.nextDouble();
        double t2_col2 = t2.nextDouble();
        double t2_col3 = t2.nextDouble();

        double index = Arrays.binarySearch(
                arr,
                t1_id
        );
        if (index>0){
            Matrix t2_matrix = new Matrix(new double[][]{
                    {t2_col1},
                    {t2_col2},
                    {t2_col3}
            });
            System.out.print("Text_1 matrix(before add)");
            t1_matrix.print(9,6);
            System.out.print("Text_1 matrix(after add)");
            t1_matrix.plus(t2_matrix).print(9,6);
            System.out.println("=============================================================");
        }

    }
}
```

**output result:**

[12.0, 20.0, 22.0, 23.0, 25.0, 33.0, 45.0, 55.0, 77.0, 86.0, 90.0]

Text_1 matrix(before add)
  86.000000
   1.235600
  -0.632500

Text_1 matrix(after add)
  89.573232
  -2.097239
   1.708300

=========split line=========

Text_1 matrix(before add)
  25.000000
   1.051200
   0.978520

Text_1 matrix(after add)
  28.573225
  -2.281637
   3.319220

=========split line=========

Text_1 matrix(before add)
  90.000000
   3.568700
  -0.897400

Text_1 matrix(after add)
  93.573237
   0.235775
   1.443600

=========split line=========

Text_1 matrix(before add)
  55.000000
  -4.125400
   1.361100

Text_1 matrix(after add)
  58.573271
  -7.458244
   3.701800

=========split line=========

If modification based on your code, i would comment 19th line which is

```
while (x.hasNext())) {
```

and 32th line which is

```
}
```

then it will runs well too; the reason is: You should not make another inside loop here, it will read all of rows from `Text_1.txt` after read first row of `Text2.txt`,when the outside loop read second row or rest rows from `Text_2.txt`, `x.hasNext()` will always return false because it reached the end of `Text_1.txt` already.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation why your code works and possibly also why OP's code doesn't work?

Comment: i think @Joakim Danielson just explained, i can't explain further..also the code itself explained well..

Comment: another suggestion for @Saswati is: debug line by line ):

Comment: Answers containing only code aren't very helpful for understanding where someone went wrong or for future visitors looking for solutions. An overview of what you did would help improve this answer a lot.

Comment: @qfrank Thank you. Your code run well. I just change two lines.`Scanner t1 = new Scanner(new File("D:\\Test_1.txt"));`
        `Scanner t2 = new Scanner(new File("D:\\Test_2.txt"));`. Hope it will solve my purpose. :)